# Adding time elapsed instead of just updating

Tags: c++, qt

I have on my dialog lineEdit which displays a time elapsed after certain operation finished it's work. So the code structure is following:

```
void some_f()
{
QTime time;
time.start();
My_Class::do_operation();//this is static fnc
line_edit->setText(QString::number(time.elapsed()));
}
```

What I cannot understand is how on earth this is possible:
While debugging all seems ok, every time this fnc is invoked the time elapsed is different but similar (within same range).
Strange things happen when this isn't in debug mode. It looks like time elapsed is ADDED TO PREVIOUS result (previous time). How/why to fix it?

Comment: code seems ok. You may have some memory problems, which cause such time increase - for example caching some data into list and not clearing it after finishing your function may cause such time increase... what are you doing in your do_operation? if nothing criminal, check your memory for corruptions with valgrind on linux or gflags, if you are on windows...

Comment: @Raiv there are no mem leaks. Checked.

Comment: well then another try - QTime should initialize itself with zeros, but try to add explicit initialization... QTime time(0,0,0,0); . in debug mode memory is always initialized with same data, but in release that is incorrect... So maybe you just use uninitialized timer, memory for it is the same each time you call your function, so old timer values preserve and new data is adding to old...

Comment: If explicit initialization still doesn't help: Below `time.start()`, output `time` (or `time.toString()`) somewhere, see if it is always the same. Another possibility is that the source of the behaviour is in the `do_operation` function, though I can't tell that without looking into it ;-)

Comment: @Tim and Raiv - I've changed this do_operation from static to 'regular' and it works now as intended. Strange.